# .Htaccess to redirect all files in various folders and subfolders by removing a particular word

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a images gallery and I am wondering if its possible to strip the word normal_ from the file name of each file in various folders and sub-folders, i got some 500 folders and over 50,000 image files.

I am trying to get -

http://www.photos.com/gallery/albums/1/normal_image1.jpg to http://www.photos.com/gallery/albums/1/image1.jpg

http://www.photos.com/gallery/albums/events/10/normal_photo2.jpg to http://www.photos.com/gallery/albums/events/10/photo2.jpg

So basically I want to redirect 301 all the files without the word normal. I am not sure how do to it recursively for all folders and sub-folders for the files within.

Answer (score 2):

Simple enough. Put the `.htaccess` file in your site's root directory with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)normal_(.*)$ /$1$2 [L,R=301]
```

By putting it in the root directory, all sub-folders will inherit the rules in this file.